# c# sort list by input index appearance in the list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, search

In my code I get a string as input from the user and return to him a list of names(strings) that consist inside themselves the users input.

I wish to sort this list by the index of the input in the first name and last name, with priority to the first name. example:

User input string: Da

desired result: 
"David Gal"
"American Dad"
"Adam Jones"

example explanation:
"David Gal" is first because the index of "Da" is 0 in the first name.
"America Dad" is second because "Da" is also first in the last name but last names have lesser priority than first names when the index is equal.
"Adam Jones" is last because "Da" has the lowest index appearance in his name.

**Edit:**
I've found the answer but I don't have enough reputation to answer myself so here it is:

```cs
listToSort.OrderBy(contact => 
               contact.Name
                 .Split(' ')
                 .Select((WordInName, WordIndex) => 
                         (uint)WordInName.IndexOf(SearchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) + WordIndex / ((double)WordIndex + 1)
                                )
                                .Min()
                        );
```

Comment: `list.Where(` _your code here_ `).OrderBy(` _your code here_ `)`, just fill missing expressions with **your own attempt** (feel free to also add a `.ToList()` if you need it).

Comment: How are the names delimited in the user input?

Comment: i create regex expression from the user input that look like this: wordRegex = new BsonRegularExpression(word + ".*", "im");.
than, using the mongodriver library i make this query:
Query<Contact>.EQ(x => x.Name, wordRegex)

Comment: The question is closed now. If/When it is reopened, you will need to post your answer from the question as an actual answer and remove your answer from the question. It has nothing to do with reputation that you can't post now. Some people use the *too broad* close reason when they encounter questions that state what they want to do without showing any effort. I don't think your question is *too* broad, but it seems broad.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list looks like this:

```
var input = new List<string>
{
    "David Gal", 
    "American Dad", 
    "Adam Jones"
};
```

This will give you a sorted set:

```
var search = "da";

var results = input
    .OrderBy(w => 
        w.Split(' ')
         .Select(x => x.ToLower().IndexOf(search)).Max());
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. I'll ask someone from my job to explain to me how it works exactly.

Comment: @DavidG- This is not working as expected. Check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/vKkBHE.

Comment: @Rahul Singh Thanks for pointing out. i checked it brefly and its seemed fine at start. ill try to expend it and post the answer if no one will do it before me.